# Is it a good practice to have a subdomain for a big project?

Tags: website-design, simplicity

We're (a company) designing three big projects:

One is used for purchase products, one for educational matters and the last but not least is our social network.

Some of our colleagues think that it's a good practice to have them all in one domain, but some other (like me) think that is not as much authoritative as it is in a separate domain.

What are pros and cons of them.

We're actually in a dilemma, what should we do?

Any suggestion?

Comment: @BenBrocka: Not really related. In that question, they had related content. Here, it's 3 unrelated parts of business operations.

Comment: @OP: What is "purchase products"? Is that the products that your company makes?

Comment: It can be everything, but it starts with our product and will grow in the near future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest pro is likely that these are 3 very different sites and that you likely won't be running them all off of the same back end system. As such, it's likely easier to have them as separate domains--even if just separate sub-domains.

Comment: Something flashed in mind, I think the good practice would be to have separate domains, but they need one registration like stackoverflow which connects with stackexchange. Isn't that ideal @DA01?

Comment: yes, that's ideal. But also may be a daunting task if the sites are running off of different systems. Doable, but will take some work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to cross-promote, have them in one place. Else there's no reason why they should better not be on respective (sub-)domains.

Answer (score 1):

A separate sub-domain per code-site is a very good idea. This means that if the purchasing system is down for any reason, you can explain that purchasing.acme.com is unavailable, but learning.acme.com and social.acme.com are both fine. That is easier than explaining that parts of intranet.acme.com are down, but other parts are up - people are very binary in their interpretation.

You also have the more formal reporting advantage, that rather than admitting that intranet.acme.com was partially unavailable for 4 days in the year, purchasing.acme.com was down for 2, learnig and social were only down for 1. That looks much better.

Comment: When part of site (subdomain) is down for specific reason, then the whole site wil be down! To be frank I didn't get your point at all!

Comment: If the system of one part is down, it doesn't mean that they will all be down.